# How can I sort an Enumerable from a class model obtained using method all in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, block

**My problem:**

*The model class:*

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :create_date, :last_update_date, :text, :title
end
```

And from a method within a controller I want to achieve something like that:

```
def index
    @recent_questions = Question.all.sort {|a, b|  a <=> b}
end
```

where can I get the resulting Enumerable `order by create_date` from most recently to oldest

What should I modify within the class definition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scope.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  scope :by_time, order("created_at DESC")
end

# in controller
def index
  @recent_questions = Question.by_time
end
```

Also don't use `all` in controller unless you are using Rails 4. `all` will return an Array which could be very heavy when you have lots of data. scope will return `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which only run query when needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new in ruby and that stuff was giving me headache

Answer (score 1):

Use Ruby’s [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
@recent_questions.sort_by(&:create_date)
```